# Scripting languages execute the line which has an error and don't output anything or it don't execute it at all?

Tags: scripting, interpreter, execute

Do scripting languages execute the line which has an error and don't output anything or it don't execute it at all?
Like what is the process when scripting languages have an error line in the code?

I know it doesn't execute it right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the nature of the error. (It also might depend on the language or interpreter.)

If the line has a syntax error (or other error that the interpreter treats similarly), the interpreter will almost certainly not execute the line. In fact, it might not execute *any* lines. (It's possible that an interpreter could 'repair' a syntax error and then execute the line, but I don't think that's common.)

If the line has a different kind of error, the interpreter will execute the line until it encounters the error.